# Simultaneous development in one angular project

Tags: angular, repository

Fairly new in angluar. I'm about to start an angular project alongside other developers.

Question is how can we share our angular development project with each other wherein we can work simultaneously, like a continuous integration setup.

If you can also share how to implement this, then it'll be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a nightmare of conflicts. Just use version control.

Comment: You can upload your code to a repositories like GitHub, bitbucket by creating branches from the master branch and then create pull requests for your code get it approved and merge it to master. Version control tools are used for this purpose like git.

Answer (score -1):

Put the code in GitHub or another source control repo. Run your tests in a CI setup with a GitHub webhook.